# VS code: Updated PYTHONPATH in settings. Import autocomplete now works, but module not found when running program

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, python-import

I have been trying to fix a problem while running python files in VSCode. I have a directory with a program `my_program.py` that imports a module `personal_functions.py` from a folder `packages_i_made`.

```
project
├── .env
└── folder_a
    ├── my_program.py

my_packages
├── __init__.py
└── packages_i_made
    ├── __init__.py
    └── personal_functions.py
```

---

`my_program.py` contains:

```
from packages_i_made import personal_functions as pf
```

When typing this import line, the text autocompletes. Previously autocomplete didn't work and imports failed with the module not being recognized, which is why I added the `.env` file which contains `PYTHONPATH="C:/Users/user_1/my_packages"` . I also updated the workspace settings with a path to the `.env` file.

I hoped this would fix my import issue, but imports still fail as before when running the file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user_1\...\...\project\folder_a\my_program.py", line 1, in <module>
    from packages_i_made import personal_functions as pf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packages_i_made'
```

I'm an utter beginner to programming, but my interpretation of the issue is this: As far as I can tell, Pylance can see the `my_packages` directory and recognize the packages inside it. However, the python interpreter fails to recognize the path to `my_packages`. If it's important, the `my_packages` directory is in my system path.  I've been banging my head against this for days.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your workspace contains project and my_packages, try `from my_packages.packages_i_made import personal_functions as pf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve the problem is to use the `sys.path.append` method above your import statement to indicate the path. For you, the code should look like this:

```json
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Users/user_1/my_packages")

from packages_i_made import personal_functions as pf
```

You set the `.env` file just to let vscode intellisense (*pylance* for python) see the package, but in fact the python interpreter still cannot access your package. This effect is the same as adding `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` configuration in ***settings.json***, it will add additional import search resolution path.

The difference this brings is that when you write import code you get autocompletion and the yellow warning squiggly line disappears. But when you run the code, you still get errors because the python interpreter doesn't actually have access to your package.

VS code uses the currently open folder as the workspace. So which folder you open in vscode is also critical.

Comment: Where is sys.path? Is that the same thing as the environment variable I set in windows settings? If so, I already have the proper directory added to my path. 

Unfortunately, this error occurs regardless of which workspace I have open. My_packages is set as its own separate workspace. Is it possible to import modules from a different workspace?

I think this would be instantly fixed if everything was in the same workspace, but since I'm trying to learn to work with different workspaces, I didn't want to do that.

Comment: Importing from a different workspace requires using the method in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open the vscode from your project root folder. It should work then.